# How do I locate applications that drain my battery on a MacBook Pro?

Tags: macos, macbook-pro, power

I purchased a new Macbook Pro and have since downloaded a ton of applications and add ins.  I think some of these apps are responsible for draining my battery too quickly.

- How do I identify what applications are responsible for this, or otherwise experience what a "clean machine" feels like?

Back in the day I used Extensions Manager on OS 7.x to turn off add ins that would slow my machine down.  What is the equivalent in OSX?

Answer (score 5):

The Activity Monitor template in Instruments shows average CPU use over time:

[image]

You can also use `top -o time` or Activity Monitor to sort processes by CPU time.

[image]

CPU time doesn't always correlate with CPU use though. It's reset when a process exits, so the list won't include old mdworker processes or applications that have been quit manually.

Comment: I wonder how difficult it would be to use this information more rigorously, i.e. to capture processes that start and stop, and compute a ranking since last boot.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately there's no real quick and easy answer for this questions, but her are a few tips.

1. You can hold down *SHIFT* at startup to disable non-essential kernel extensions and startup items. However you will lose some functionality (such as graphics acceleration.) See http://support.apple.com/kb/HT1564
2. If you are using a 15 or 17-inch MacBook Pro, then you can use System Profiler/System Information to see if your programs are turning on the *Discrete* graphics card (which uses more power than *Integrated* graphics.) See http://support.apple.com/kb/HT4152
3. Use Activity Monitor, located in Applications -> Utilities, and check for unusual CPU or Disk Activity. Make sure to click "My Processes" and change to "All Processes." You can click on a column header such as CPU% or Real Mem to sort processes/Applications. Perhaps purchasing a program like iStatMenus (which provides real-time monitoring in the Mac menubar) will be helpful. See http://bjango.com/mac/istatmenus/

HTH

Answer (score 0):

I would monitor the activity such as CPU. Spinning hard drives that are constantly being accessed cause major battery drain and I would recommend a SSD  if you don't already have one.